# Create simple PL/SQL variable - Use Variable in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

Thanks for looking...

I've spent hours researching this and I can't believe it's that difficult to do something in PL/SQL that is simple in TSQL.

I have a simple query that joins 2 tables:

```
     Select DISTINCT
      to_char(TO_DATE('1899123000', 'yymmddhh24')+ seg.NOM_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS "Record Date"
    , cd.CODE
    , EMP.ID
    , EMP.SHORT_NAME

    FROM
     EWFM.GEN_SEG seg join EWFM.SEG_CODE cd ON seg.SEG_CODE_SK = cd.SEG_CODE_SK
     join EMP on seg.EMP_SK = EMP.EMP_SK
    where NOM_DATE = vMyDate;
```

I use Toad Date Point and I'm querying against an Oracle Exadata source.  The resulting query will be dropped into a visualization tool like QlikView or Tableau.  I'd like to create a simple variable to use the the WHERE clause as you can see in the code.

In this example, NOM_DATE is an integer such as 42793 (2/27/2017) as you can see in the first row "Record Date".  Nothing new here, not very exciting... Until... I tried to create a variable to make the query more dynamic.

I've tried a surprising variety of examples found here, all have failed.  Such as:
`declare
    myDate number(8);
  Begin
    myDate := 42793;`
--Fail ORA-06550 INTO Clause is expected

```
variable nomDate NUMBER
DEFINE nomDate = 42793
EXEC : nomDate := ' & nomDate'
...where NOM_DATE = ( & nomDate) ;
```

--ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

and

```
variable nomDate NUMBER;
EXEC nomDate := 42793;
select count(DET_SEG_SK) from DET_SEG
where NOM_DATE = :nomDate;
```

--ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

and several more.. hopefully you get the idea.  I've spent a few hours researching stackoverflow for a correct answer but as you can see, I'm asking you.  From simple declarations like "Var" to more complex " DECLARE, BEGIN, SELECT INTO...." to actually creating Functions, using cursors to iterate the output.... I still can't make a simple variable to use in a Where clause.

Please explain the error of my ways.

--Forlorn SQL Dev

Comment: Firstly, I assume you mean PL/SQL, not TSQL. Secondly, I tried you first example, and I do not see a problem; it works for me. So I think it's must be something very simple or very bizarre !  Can you cut/paste your whole (first) example?

Comment: Inside PL/SQL (a named package/procedure/function etc) you can just declare variables in the `declare` section and then refer to them wherever you like. Your example beginning `declare mydate number(8);` works fine (just needs an `end;`) and I can't see how it could give `INTO clause is expected` since that only applies to `select` statements. The `variable` and `define` syntax is really from the SQL*Plus command line tool which is emulated in various ways by desktop applications so you may need to explain how you are running it.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is not the variable declaration but the report output - something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351489/is-it-possible-to-output-a-select-state-from-a-pl-sql-block/351752

Comment: BobC: here's the first example in it's entirety
'      declare
      myDate number(8);
    Begin
      myDate := 42793;
    
  SELECT DISTINCT
    to_char(TO_DATE('1899123000', 'yymmddhh24')+ seg.NOM_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS "Record Date"
  , cd.CODE
  , EMP.ID
  , EMP.SHORT_NAME
  , seg.MEMO
  , seg.AUDIT_INS_DATE

  FROM
   EWFM.GEN_SEG seg join EWFM.SEG_CODE cd ON  seg.SEG_CODE_SK = cd.SEG_CODE_SK
   join EMP on seg.EMP_SK = EMP.EMP_SK
  where NOM_DATE = myDate;
  end; 
'
Thanks for the interest

Comment: @mf.cummings. I don't see your example...

Comment: William Roberts:  I agree the DECLARE format seems most likely but of the several different attempts I tried, I received the same error. Here's the code:
'Declare
 myDate number(8) := 42793;
BEGIN
Select DISTINCT
  to_char(TO_DATE('1899123000', 'yymmddhh24')+ eg.NOM_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS "Record Date"
, cd.CODE
, EMP.ID
, EMP.SHORT_NAME
  FROM
  EWFM.GEN_SEG seg join EWFM.SEG_CODE cd ON seg.SEG_CODE_SK = cd.SEG_CODE_SK
  join EMP on seg.EMP_SK = EMP.EMP_SK
 where NOM_DATE = myDate;
END;'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an implicit cursor, you have to select then INTO variables. Now I d not know the data types of you variables, so I have just guessed in this example below, but hopefully you get the point.

Two other things I should mention

1. Why are you TO_CHARing you DATE. Just use a DATE datatype. Also, I think your format mask is wrong too 1899123000 does not match yymmddhh24.
2. In explicit cursor expects exactly one row; no rows and you get NO_DATA_FOUND; more than one and you get TOO_MANY_ROWS

> > ```
> > Declare 
> >    myDate number(8) := 42793; 
> >     /* These 4 variable data types are a guess */
> >    v_record_date varchar2(8);
> >    v_cd_code varchar2(10);
> >    v_emp_id number(4);
> >    v_emp_short_name varchar2(100);
> >  BEGIN 
> >  Select DISTINCT to_char(TO_DATE('1899123000', 'yymmddhh24')
> >                      + eg.NOM_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS "Record Date" 
> >  , cd.CODE 
> >  , EMP.ID 
> >  , EMP.SHORT_NAME 
> >  INTO v_record_date, v_cd_code, v_emp_id, v_emp_short_name
> >  FROM EWFM.GEN_SEG seg 
> >  join EWFM.SEG_CODE cd 
> >    ON seg.SEG_CODE_SK = cd.SEG_CODE_SK 
> >  join EMP 
> >      on seg.EMP_SK = EMP.EMP_SK 
> >  where NOM_DATE = myDate; 
> >  END;
> >  /
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

```
VARIABLE vMyDate NUMBER;

BEGIN
  :vMyDate  := 42793;
END;
/

-- or
-- EXEC :vMyDate := 42793;

SELECT DISTINCT
       TO_CHAR( DATE '1899-12-30' + seg.NOM_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS "Record Date"
     , cd.CODE
     , EMP.ID
     , EMP.SHORT_NAME
FROM   EWFM.GEN_SEG seg
       join EWFM.SEG_CODE cd
       ON seg.SEG_CODE_SK = cd.SEG_CODE_SK
       join EMP
       on seg.EMP_SK = EMP.EMP_SK
WHERE  NOM_DATE = :vMyDate;
```

Comment: So Close! I typed it almost exactly omitting the / after END; (I was under the impression that was a SQL* command to treat the lines as a block) and it failed.  I did it again with the / and the Bind Variable box popped up 2x, I entered the correct value in it both times and it ran as expected.

I have more to learn about binding variables but this is the closest to correct answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

You put the variables with getter and setter in a package.

Then use a view that uses the package getter

Personally I prefer to use a collection that way I can do a select * from table (packagage.func(myparam))