# Build select stored procedure in Oracle 12

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am primarily a .NET programmer, and occasionally build MS SQL Server stored procedures.

I need to build a procedure in Oracle to select and return some records, based on one or many parameters. I tried building one already, but have stopped in frustration.

Here is an example of what I want to create :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TS_COLLISIONS_SEARCH(
        county IN VARCHAR2,
        township IN VARCHAR2,
        col_MRN IN VARCHAR2,
        answer OUT VARCHAR2)

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER, CITY, ROAD_NAME
      INTO answer
      FROM DWOBDEV.OBIEE_TS_COLLISION_FACT_VW
    WHERE  COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER = col_MRN
    AND    TOWNSHIP = township
    AND    COUNTY = county;

END P_TS_COLLISIONS_SEARCH;
```

I get these errors:

> Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(11,7): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00947: not enough values

How would I build this in Oracle 12?

Comment: This question does not show ANY effort or research. Here is a great place to start. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+a+stored+procedure+in+oracle+with+parameters&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Try to run the query that's in the procedure; it will give a result with 3 columns. In your procedure, you're trying to put these 3 values inside a single scalar variable, so... Also, notice that if your query will give more than one row, scalar variables will not be enough to host the results

Comment: If you just want a query that returns results to the prompt, try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

- You are selecting three columns INTO a single column.  If you use this to return a single row, you have to match the number of columns to the number of variables selected to.
- You are selecting the id into the result, but you already have it as an input value.  Reselecting it would be redundant.
- Also, you seem to be passing in an id already, it is unclear if this is a PK and if it is, you would not need to query on additional values.  It would make a bit more sense to just pass in a single ID argument to get a specific row then an additional proc to take other arguments to match on other column values.

Here is a version of your proc that works.  If you are intending to return more than one row, you'll need to change to return a cursor instead.  Use the documentation / web search to find an example.

```
create table OBIEE_TS_COLLISION_FACT_VW
(collision_master_record_number number,
 county varchar2(50),
 township varchar2(50),
 city  varchar2(50),
 road_name varchar2(50));

insert into obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw values (1, 'WINCHESTER',     'SPRINGFIELD', 'MOSCOW', 'STATION');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TS_COLLISIONS_SEARCH(
    county IN VARCHAR2,
    township IN VARCHAR2,
    col_MRN IN VARCHAR2,
    city_o OUT VARCHAR2,
    road_name_o OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CITY, ROAD_NAME
      INTO city_o, road_name_o
      FROM OBIEE_TS_COLLISION_FACT_VW
    WHERE  COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER = col_MRN
    AND    TOWNSHIP = township
    AND    COUNTY = county;

END P_TS_COLLISIONS_SEARCH;

declare
    l_id number := 1;
    l_township VARCHAR2(50) := 'TOWNSHIP';
    l_county VARCHAR2(50) := 'COUNTY';
    l_city varchar2(50);
    l_road_name varchar2(50);
begin
    P_TS_COLLISIONS_SEARCH(l_county, l_township, l_id, l_city, l_road_name);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_city||'|'||l_road_name);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess as I don't know what kind of output you want, but maybe this:

```
create or replace procedure p_ts_collisions_search
    ( p_col_mrn   obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw.collision_master_record_number%type
    , p_township  obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw.township%type
    , p_county    obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw.county%type )
as
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for
        select collision_master_record_number
             , city
             , road_name
        from   obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw
        where  collision_master_record_number = p_col_mrn
        and    township = p_township
        and    county = p_county;

    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
```

Note that I have prefixed my parameters with `p_` to differentiate them from the database columns, because `and township = township` doesn't achieve much. (An alternative would be to label them with the procedure name, e.g. `p_ts_collisions_search.township`.)

Dummy data:

```
create view obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw
as
select 1 as collision_master_record_number
     , 'London' as city
     , 'Bond Street' as road_name
     , 'West End' as township
     , 'Lalaland' as county
from dual;
```

Demo in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> exec p_ts_collisions_search(1, 'West End', 'Lalaland');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER CITY   ROAD_NAME
------------------------------ ------ -----------
                             1 London Bond Street
```

However, it won't work everywhere, as the client needs to be able to process implicit results:

```
SQL> call p_ts_collisions_search(1, 'West End', 'Lalaland');
call p_ts_collisions_search(1, 'West End', 'Lalaland')
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29478: Implicit result cannot be returned through this statement.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2785
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2779
ORA-06512: at "WILLIAM.P_TS_COLLISIONS_SEARCH", line 17
```

Alternatively, you could return the result set explicitly via an `out` parameter:

```
create or replace procedure p_ts_collisions_search
    ( p_col_mrn   obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw.collision_master_record_number%type
    , p_township  obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw.township%type
    , p_county    obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw.county%type
    , p_results   out sys_refcursor )
as
begin
    open p_results for
        select collision_master_record_number
             , city
             , road_name
        from   obiee_ts_collision_fact_vw
        where  collision_master_record_number = p_col_mrn
        and    township = p_township
        and    county = p_county;
end;
```

Demo:

```
SQL> var results refcursor
SQL> set autoprint on
SQL> exec p_ts_collisions_search(1, 'West End', 'Lalaland', :results);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

COLLISION_MASTER_RECORD_NUMBER CITY   ROAD_NAME
------------------------------ ------ -----------
                             1 London Bond Street
```

Comment: Thanks all for the input! It's been very helpful!