# Calling PLsql script with an anonymous PL SQL block from SOCI

Tags: c++, oracle, plsql, soci

I'm searching for a way to call an anonymous PLsql block through SOCI. The data transfer takes place through a refcursor that was previously created as a variable in the script:

```
variable rc refcursor
declare
   v_obj_id number(4,0) := 1;
   v_obj_def varchar(30);
   v_obj_type number := 1;
begin
  open :rc for
     select v_obj_id, OBJ_DEF_ID
     from MY_OBJECT_DEFS
     where OBJECT_TYPE = v_obj_type;
end;
```

I need to read the refcursor from my application to retrieve the data. I tried to execute the above through a `soci::statement` but it gives me the error: `ORA-24333: zero iteration count`. The PLsql script works fine when executed in SqlPlus.

1. How can I make the connection between the statement and the
   refcursor rc? Should I use some other SOCI construct (other than statement) for this purpose?
2. I understand there are two instructions in the above
   script; (i. the refcursor creation, ii. the anonymous PLsql block
   itself). I'm not sure whether its possible to call multiple
   instructions in a single SOCI statement. Can this be confirmed?

Following is the what I tried. The `sSQL` contains the above PLsql script:

```
dbConn.open("...");
int iObjId;
std::string iObjDefId;
soci::indicator ind_iObjId = soci::i_ok,
        ind_iObjDefId = soci::i_ok;

soci::statement stmt(dbConn);
stmt.alloc();
stmt.prepare(sSQL);
stmt.exchange(soci::into(iObjId, ind_iObjId));
stmt.exchange(soci::into(iObjDefId, ind_iObjDefId));
stmt.define_and_bind();
stmt.execute(false);

while (stmt.fetch())
{
    if (soci::i_ok == ind_iObjId)
        std::cout << "Obj ID: " << iObjId << std::endl;

    if (soci::i_ok == ind_iObjDefId)
        std::cout << "Obj Def ID: " << iObjDefId << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT: I'm using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

The statement `variable rc refcursor` is neither SQL nor PL/SQL but part of Oracle's [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG453) command-line utility and compatible third party products. I don't know C++ but presumably you would need to define a ref cursor object in the host program.

If this is not feasible, and you are on Oracle 12.1 or later, it's possible that you could use an [implicit result set](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#FEATURENO10020) construction, along the lines of

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select * from dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
```

as discussed in [Is it possible to output a SELECT state from a PL/SQL block?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471)