# Two (PL)/SQL queries using sqoop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqoop

I'm trying to import data from Oracle database to HDFS by using `sqoop 1.4.6`. I have no problem doing simple imports to HDFS or hive tables by using `--table table_name` or `--query SELECT <...>` statements.

However, my question: is there a way to import the table with executing a certain PL/SQL procedure first?

For example, assume there exists a procedure `set_date(date IN DATE)`, specified in the Oracle database that is used to set the report date for the data. With usual JDBC tools (i.e., `ROracle` package if working from `R`) two queries are required for the same connection to pull the data:

1) `BEGIN set_date(#some_date#); END;`

2) `SELECT * FROM table_name;`

Is it possible to achieve the same result using `sqoop`? I've tried mixing the two queries into one by the following approach:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@LINK:PORT:SID \
--username user -P \
--target-dir /some/directory \
--query "BEGIN set_date(#some_date#); END; SELECT * FROM table_name"
```

But apparently the whole query is assumed to be in PL/SQL format, therefore the 2) part of the query is not formulated as expected. Also, I've tried `eval`'ing only the `set_date` part of the query, which seems to work fine, so the only problem is to correctly execute the 2) SQL query.

Is it possible to call a second query using the same sqoop connection?
Is it possible to mix 1) and 2) statements into one in order to get the same result (for now a simple select table would be enough) using sqoop?

Note: I don't have much experience working with SQL and PL/SQL, so sorry if I didn't specify some parts clearly enough.

Comment: I don't know sqoop, but if you are on Oracle 12.1 you might try combining the two statements into a single anonymous block and returning an implicit result set, along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/a/43451151/230471

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a wild guess as I don't know Sqoop, but from Oracle 12.1 an anonymous PL/SQL block cab return result sets implicitly, so if Sqoop supports this it's just possible that the block could be:

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    set_date(#some_date#);

    open rc for select * from table_name;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a look, though I'm currently on Oracle 11g.

Comment: After running it I get the error: ``PLS-00201: identifier 'DMBS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT' must be declared``, probably due to the Oracle version used? Additionally, tried openning ``:rc`` and printing it afterwards, but so far without luck. Are there any other known workarounds?

Comment: Implicit result sets are new in 12c.