# how can we return records from pl/sql stored procedure without taking out parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, database-cursor

My Question is "How can we return multiple records from pl/sql stored procedure without taking **OUT** parameter".I got this doubt because if we are using cursors or refcursor in **out** parameter it may degrade performance.So what is the solution??

Comment: You could populate an array I suppose, but that is likely to perform worse than a cursor. You can have 
 [an implicit cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471) to avoid declaring one, but it's still a cursor.

Comment: What evidence do you have that it will degrade performance?

Comment: That's not really *returning* anything, but - you could populate some table with that stored procedure, and then - somewhere else (in a report, for example) select data stored in that table.

Answer (score 1):

As OldProgrammer wrote, i think the performance of a cursor wouldn't be you problem. But here a Solution anyway:

You can return custom types like `Table of number`. If it's only a list of numbers you could return a `table of numbers`. If you Want to return rows from a table you could return `table of 'tablename'%ROWTYPE`. But i guess you want to create some custom types.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PUWB_INT.MyOrderType AS OBJECT
(
    OrderId NUMBER,
    OrderName VARCHAR2 (255)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PUWB_INT.MyOrderListType AS TABLE OF MYORDERtype
/
```

Now we can use them similar to a `return myNumberVariable;`

Let's build a function (procedures don't have return values):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUWB_INT.MyFunction (SomeInput VARCHAR2)
    RETURN MyOrderListType
IS
    myOrderList   MyOrderListType := MyOrderListType ();
BEGIN
    FOR o IN (SELECT 1 AS Id, 'One' AS Name FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 AS Id, 'Two' AS Name FROM DUAL)
    LOOP
        myOrderList.EXTEND ();
        myOrderList (myOrderList.COUNT) := MyOrderType (o.Id, o.Name || '(' || SomeInput || ')');
    END LOOP;

    RETURN myOrderList;
END MyFunction;
/
```

Now we can call the function and get a table of our custom-type:

```
DECLARE
    myOrderList   MyOrderListType;
    myOrder       MyOrderType;
BEGIN
    myOrderList := MyFunction ('test');

    FOR o IN myOrderList.FIRST .. myOrderList.LAST
    LOOP
        myOrder := myOrderList (o);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Id: ' || myOrder.OrderId || ', Name: ' || myOrder.OrderName);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Be aware, that the calling schema, has to know the type.