# trying to execute the query for different db links using for loop concatinating dblink.but its throwing db link expected error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute the query for different db links. I am using a for loop concatenated dblink. But it is throwing a db link expected error.

```
begin
for i in (select db_link from db_table )
loop
select * FROM table@||i.db_link; 
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Its a sql query....

Comment: oracle normal sql query...

Comment: what do you want to achieve

Comment: I want to run same query in different db's. So using for loop one by one db I am taking and  concatinating with table name in the place of  dblink.But still it's throwing dblink expected error

Comment: Thanks for edits now can anybody help me in solving this¿?

Comment: Please search for CURSOR processing in PL/SQL, espetially *dynamic cursor*, which you will need for parametrizing the DB link.

Comment: Can u give me an example how can I achieve that??

Comment: declare
vsql varchar2(2000);
begin
for i in (select db_link from db_table)
loop
vsql:='select * FROM table@'||i.db_link;
execute immediate 'vsql';
end loop;
end;
 itried above it'snot throwing any error but not getting any data...

Comment: In PL/SQL blocks, you have to tell it what you want to print to output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351489/is-it-possible-to-output-a-select-statement-from-a-pl-sql-block

Comment: Kfinity -didn't get how it solve my case