# How to Select a Variable As Query Result in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've looked high and low but have not been able to figure this out.

I have this function defined in Oracle:

```
FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(
    INPUTVAR1 IN OUT NUMBER,
    INPUTVAR2 VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER;
```

The person who created this function is basically returning the input parameter if it's not 0. Otherwise if INPUTVAR1 is 0, it will return a new value. I want that new value.

In T-SQL it's so simple it's stupid:

```
DECLARE @MyVar INT = 0;
SET @MyVar = MY_FUNCTION(@MyVar, NULL);
SELECT @MyVar as Result;
```

But In Oracle, I cannot figure out how to return the return value as a result. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE MyVar NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
MyVar := MY_FUNCTION(INPUTVAR1 => MyVar, INPUTVAR2 => NULL)
END;
```

But I can't figure out how to use MyVar in the result. I definitely cannot select it. I tried `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MyVar);` but no luck.

Anyone know how I can return the value of `MyVar`?

Comment: as if `null` and `zero` are confused ...

Comment: How are you running this? SQL*Plus or some other tool? also, what do you mean with "return the value"? Do you want to see it on screen, return it to a caller and then use it, say, in another procedure, … ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer IDE

Comment: From your own answer, it seems you want to return a **result set** or **cursor**, not the function result. That question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471 (Perhaps answering @Aleksej's question would have clarified things. In another comment you mention it's for an ETL tool, though above you said you suggested it was for use in SQL Developer, a development IDE.)

Comment: You caught me. I was testing in sql developer before moving it to my etl tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to find this solution which works only if you have 12c or above JDBC drivers:

```
DECLARE MyVar NUMBER := 0;
    rc sys_refcursor; 
BEGIN
MyVar := MY_FUNCTION(INPUTVAR1 => MyVar, INPUTVAR2 => NULL)

open rc for SELECT MyVar FROM dual; 
dbms_sql.return_result(rc); 

END;
```

I'd like to meet the person who thought it was a good idea to have a FUNCTION with both IN/OUT parameters and a return value.

Comment: The 12c new feature here is the implicit result set. Prior to 12c you could explicitly return a ref cursor. How to do this will depend on your ETL framework.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine the function to not having an `OUT` parameter:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(
    INPUTVAR1 IN NUMBER,
    INPUTVAR2 IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN INPUTVAR1;
END;
/
```

Then you can use it in an SQL query:

```sql
SELECT MY_FUNCTION( INPUTVAR1 => 0, INPUTVAR2 => NULL ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
```

Output:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | ----: |
> |     0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=26751edcb1bb34917be59893425df6b7)*

---

**Update**

If you cannot redefine the function to remove the `OUT` parameter then write a wrapper around it:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION_WRAPPER(
    INPUTVAR1 IN NUMBER,
    INPUTVAR2 IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  var1 NUMBER := INPUTVAR1;
BEGIN
  RETURN MY_FUNCTION( INPUTVAR1 => var1, INPUTVAR2 => INPUTVAR2 );
END;
/
```

Then you can call it from an SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT MY_FUNCTION_WRAPPER( INPUTVAR1 => 0, INPUTVAR2 => NULL ) AS value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Output:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | ----: |
> |     0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b41a3b7259d967916f112c1805c3732e)*

Comment: I wish I could remove the out parameter but I can't as it will break any existing callers.

Comment: @Sal Updated - write a wrapper around the function that does not have the `OUT` parameter.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating a MY_FUNCTION2 function but I might have to go with this. I did find another solution which I'm posting here but because I can't update the java drivers (I'm using a third party ETL tool) I cannot use that solution.

Answer (score 1):

dbms_output works fine for me:

```
create or replace FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(
    INPUTVAR1 IN OUT NUMBER,
    INPUTVAR2 VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER is
begin
    if inputvar1 = 0 then
        return -1;
    else
        return inputvar1;
    end if;
end;
/

declare
  my_var number := 0;
  my_var2 number := 0;
begin
  my_var2 := my_function(my_var, 'A');
  dbms_output.put_line('my_var:' || my_var);
  dbms_output.put_line('my_var2:' || my_var2);
end;
/

my_var:0
my_var2:-1
```

Edit: I am a little concerned about having an OUT variable in a function. That's usually a sign of poor coding, which is why I used 2 variables above, so you could see whether the function was "returning" the new value by modifying INPUTVAR1, or by using the return value. Or both.

Comment: This function was created 12 years ago by who knows who. Also, dbms_output.put_line won't work for me as I cannot access the output buffer from my etl tool unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your original Oracle code, with dbms_output, is correct. Basically, after calling a function you use the assigned variable exactly as if you had assigned it a value (same as SQL Server).
So a function call 
"x := some_function(y)" that returns a value (lets say 9), is after the call exactly the same as if you had written 
"x := 9". So again your function was correct. 

However, you indicated you use SQL Developer. My guess is you didn't have  dbms_output turned on. To do that on SQL Developer menu bar  select View then click Dbms output. This will open a dbms_output window. But your not quite done. It the Dbms output window click the large green **+**, select the appropriate schema (if needed) and click ok. Dbms_output will now be shown in that window.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 DECLARE MyVar NUMBER := 0;
   varout VARCHAR2();
 BEGIN
 --MyVar := MY_FUNCTION(INPUTVAR1 => MyVar, INPUTVAR2 => NULL)
 select MY_FUNCTION(INPUTVAR1 => MyVar, INPUTVAR2 => NULL) INTO varout from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(MyVar);
  END;
```

Comment: You cannot use a function in an SQL statement if it has an `OUT` parameter.