# Oracle: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, exec, procedure

```
create procedure employee_get
(
   c_Emp  out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
is
begin
   open c_Emp for
   select a.last_name, b.department_id, b.department_name from employee a inner join department b on a.department_id = b.department_id
   order by a.last_name asc ;
end employee_get;
-- run
var c_out refcursor;
exec employee_get(:c_out);
print :c_out;
```

Everything was fine until I made the Run command. I'm new member, please help me. Thanks and respect!

Comment: Please clarify your problem, format your code, and add some explanation about what you trying to  achieve.

Comment: Your procedure takes one parameter, but your `exec` statement doesn't supply that parameter.

Comment: @BobJarvis, I tried following your instructions, but it still didn't work

Comment: `drop procedure employee_get` would drop the procedure if the syntax was correct, but it is missing its `;` (unless you changed `sqlterminator`), and the `create procedure` statement above is missing its trailing `/`, so running the code above in SQL\*Plus will just prompt for the next line.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, i don't run the query drop procedure employee_get. It has no effect. Even if I delete it, there is still an error

Answer (score 1):

You need following code to execute the procedure:

```
create procedure employee_get
(
   c_Emp  out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
is
begin
   open c_Emp for
   select a.last_name, b.department_id, b.department_name from employee a inner join department b on a.department_id = b.department_id
   order by a.last_name asc ;
end employee_get;
/

-- EXECUTE THE PROCEDURE
DECLARE
C_OUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
-- run
employee_get(C_OUT);
dbms_sql.return_result(C_OUT); --UPDATED
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: That will miserably fail because of the EXEC call within the PL/SQL block.

Comment: Correct.. Updated it

Comment: @Tejash, My desired result is to display data. But it does not display

Comment: Then you need to use `dbms_sql.return_result(C_OUT);` as updated in the answer

Comment: @Tejash, sql navigator show mess: "component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared". I don't know why the error is so

Comment: Because you don't have privileges on the package, I presume. I've posted an alternative approach, see the answer (it can't fit into the comment and can't be formatted). And, to be *politically correct*, upvoded Tejash's answer.

Comment: `dbms_sql.return_result` requires Oracle 12.1. It's possible @ĐoànHiển is stuck with an old version, in which case there are some more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471

Comment: Missing grants would give `PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_SQL' must be declared`. However, `dbms_sql` is granted to `public` by default. `PLS-00302: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared` indicates that the package exists but the procedure doesn't, which would be the case prior to Oracle 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure which returns refcursor:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure employee_get (c_emp out sys_refcursor) is
  2  begin
  3    open c_emp for select empno, ename from emp;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Execution:

```
SQL> declare
  2    c_out sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    employee_get(c_out);
  5    dmbs_sql.return_result(c_out);
  6  end;
  7  /
  dmbs_sql.return_result(c_out);
  *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DMBS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

See with your DBA whether you can get execute privileges on DBMS_SQL package.

If not:

```
SQL> var c_out refcursor;
SQL> exec employee_get(:c_out);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :c_out

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I did like you but failed

Comment: Well, it *works* (as you can see). Please, edit your initial message and post what you did and how Oracle responded. I don't know why it failed for you.

Comment: *
   line 2: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EMPLOYEE_GET'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: The procedure accepts only one parameter, and its type is refcursor. Is that correct? If possible, post your SQL*Plus session (just like I did) which **exactly** shows every step you made, with all messages returned by Oracle. You posted some commands, but I can't tell whether it is really what you ran or not.

Comment: okie, thanks you. I'll try again. hope done. I am used to using SQL Server, switching to Oracle is more difficult than I thought. :))

Comment: True; although similar, they seem to be quite different after all. Good luck!