# Return results of query inside PL/SQL script

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible that SELECT statement inside PL/SQL block will return table records like during executing SELECT query in standard way?

I mean why code:

```sql
DECLARE
    sql_qry     VARCHAR2 (150);
BEGIN

    sql_qry:= 'SELECT ''1'' FROM dual';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_qry;
END;
/
```

after execusion returns only information: 
`PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Is it possible that SELECT statement enclosed in PL/SQL block will behave the same way like executing:

```sql
SELECT '1' FROM dual;
```

Comment: If you want to open a cursor, or populate an array, or something else, then by all means code it. What do you need it to do exactly? [This kind of thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471)

Comment: This is a very basic pl/sql question. I suggest you get  introductory book on pl/sql or see the [Oracle PL/SQL language guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm), in addition to the link @WilliamRobertson provided above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to output a SELECT statement from a PL/SQL block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351489/is-it-possible-to-output-a-select-statement-from-a-pl-sql-block)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle 12c and above you may use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`

For 11g, you may make use of this standard procedure

```
create or replace procedure return_result( l_query varchar2 )
   is
       l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
       l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
       l_status        integer;
       l_colCnt        number := 0;
       l_separator     varchar2(1);
       l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   begin
       dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  l_query, dbms_sql.native );

       dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );


           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_output.put( l_separator || l_descTbl(i).col_name );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           dbms_output.put_line('');

        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
           dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
       end loop;
       l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

       while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
               dbms_output.put( l_separator || l_columnValue );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           dbms_output.new_line;
       end loop;
       dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
   end;
/
```

Call it as

```
set serveroutput on 
EXECUTE return_result('SELECT ''1'' as col FROM dual');
```

Res

```
COL
1
```