# How to set a variable and use it in a select query in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I do something like this in oracle SQL developer?

```
DECLARE
    p_name products.product_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
    p_name := 'Strawberry';
   SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = p_name;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cursor:

```sql
DECLARE
    p_name VARCHAR2(100);
    p_cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    p_name := 'Strawberry';
    OPEN p_cur FOR
    SELECT * FROM products where product_name=p_name;

    -- do something with the cursor.
END;
/
```

Or use a SQL/Plus-style bind variable declaration:

```sql
VARIABLE p_name VARCHAR2;

BEGIN
  :p_name := 'Strawberry';
END;
/

SELECT * FROM products where product_name=:p_name;
```

If only one row will ever be returned from your query (i.e. `product_name` is `UNIQUE`) then you can use `SELECT ... INTO ...`:

```sql
DECLARE
    p_name   VARCHAR2(100);
    p_value1 products.value1%TYPE;
    p_value2 products.value2%TYPE;
    p_value3 products.value3%TYPE;
BEGIN
    p_name := 'Strawberry';

    SELECT value1, value2, value3
    INTO   p_value1, p_value2, p_value3
    FROM   products
    WHERE  product_name=p_name;

    -- do something with the values.
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    -- Handle the exception
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    NULL;
    -- Handle the exception
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the SELECT statement somewhere to put the results of the query:

```
DECLARE
  p_name VARCHAR2(100);
  aProducts_row  PRODUCTS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  p_name := 'Strawberry';

  SELECT *
    INTO aProducts_row
    FROM products
    where product_name=p_name;

  -- Add code to manipulate data in aProducts_row here, as in...

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT_NAME = ''' ||
                          aProducts_row.PRODUCT_NAME || '''');
END;
```

Or if you're expecting more than one row to be returned you can use a cursor:

```
DECLARE
  p_name VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  p_name := 'Strawberry';

  FOR aProducts_row IN (SELECT *
                          FROM products
                          where product_name=p_name)
  LOOP
    -- Add code to manipulate data in aProducts_row here, as in...

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT_NAME = ''' ||
                           aProducts_row.PRODUCT_NAME || '''');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Why is this so easy in T SQL and so complicated in PL/SQL?

Comment: T-SQL and PL/SQL use different models to accomplish the same goal. `SELECT...INTO` is present in both languages, although the syntax is slightly different. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @developer747 SQL Server allows multiple statements to be run in a single command (which opens up SQL injection vulnerabilities); Oracle only allows a single statement in each command (which still allows some SQL injection vulnerabilities but shuts down many of them - [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/) would not work in Oracle). That restriction and other differences mean they treat what you are doing slightly differently (they are different languages after all).

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I think developer747 wants to return a result set somehow, such that the block acts similarly to a query/view/table macro in Oracle. From my limited understanding of SQL Server, T-SQL can do this because it's more of a scripting language than PL/SQL.

Comment: @developer747: I guess this is a perfect example of what you learn first you learn best. To me T-SQL seems like you just throw something up and hope for the best. Difficult and totally without structure.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Basically I have this query where I need to plug in a value. I want to share that query with others. I can either ask them to change the plugged in value in the query, or I can just declare a variable and ask them to set the variable and run the query, without the need to modify the query.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is not about setting variables but is actually about output from a PL/SQL anonymous block then it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471).

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select 'Hello' as test from dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
```

You can set any variable you want using the normal [PL/SQL assignment syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-B91BEA99-974B-4CE7-8B28-A5B78A6918F7). If there is some part of the documentation that is not clear then please provide an example of what you are trying to do.